# No TypeError raised for missing abc.abstractmethod when deriving a PySide6 widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6, abc

I have an object that inherits both from a `QWidget` and an `abc.ABC` interface. See `MyWindow` in my example below.

```
import abc
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
#from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets    # It works as expected in PyQt6
#from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets    # Idem for PyQt5

class Interface(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def myMethod(self, a):
        pass

class NormalClass(Interface):
    def myMethod(self, a):
        "When you delete this method, you get an error as expected."
        print("my method normally")

class QObjectAbcMeta(type(QtCore.QObject), type(abc.ABC)):
    pass

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Interface, metaclass=QObjectAbcMeta):
    # Even though myMethod is missing, you don't get an error with PySide6
    pass

def main():
    normal = NormalClass()

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would expect that Python raises a TypeError here because the `MyWindow` class is missing a definition for the `myMethod` abstract method. However, it just runs without any error.

When I use PyQt6 I get a TypeError as expected. Also when I don't inherit from `QWidget` (my `NormalClass`) it works as expected.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @furas I believe that the OP wants to know why the exception is **not** raised, while they *do* expect it to be raised.

Comment: See: [PYSIDE-1434](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1434) and [PYSIDE-1564](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1564). These two issues were resolved as "fixed", but [according to the code review](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/pyside/pyside-setup/+/350957), it seems the fix was only partial (i.e. it doesn't currently work for all methods - but presumably will at some unspecified point in the future).

Comment: Thanks for the links @ekhumoro. (I didn't find them myself because I googled for `PySide6` instead of `PySide2`.)